# Why can we only "see" reflected light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction, vision

This is a question thats been bothering me a while. I don't even know if it makes sense or not (like if it is a physics question or becoming a philosophical one). But here it goes. The crux of my question basically is that we all know that we can't see light (like in its photon or electromagnetic wave form) directly when it is traveling past us. However, we also know that the way we see objects is by light reflecting off them. This then means that we are "seeing" the light reflecting from the object which then sends the signal to our brain saying that we are seeing a particular object. We know that both light traveling past us and light reflected from objects are made of photons (so they are the same kind)? So then my question is that what is happening to the photon of a light after it is reflected from the objects, that causes us to see it or the object, but on the other hand we can't see light as it is directly traveling past us.

Comment: Your assumption is simply wrong. It's like someone were asking why earth is flat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we see light travelling from point A to B?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196545/)

Comment: Why aren't you wounded by a bullet which does not hit you?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The key is that light must enter the eye for you to see something.

You cannot see a beam of light from a low powered laser which is not directed into your eye if the air through which the light is travelling is devoid of dust.
Adding  dust to the air and you can see the trajectory of the laser beam because of the light being reflected/scattered from the dust and enters your eye.

Similarly no atmosphere on the Moon leads to a black sky even in daylight whilst on the Earth the sky is blue.

To see something light must enter the eye and the rods (and cones) must be stimulated sufficiently for the signals to be produced for  processing by the brain.

Comment: +1 for spotting the explanation/wording that directly addressed what the asker was having difficulty understanding. Perhaps worth explicitly mentioning: this also means that there is no difference between reflected and non-reflected: you also see non-reflected light too every day, for example from the sun, light-bulbs, computer/phone screens, etc, but only because some of that light actually ends up entering your eye as well.

Comment: Wondering how many are now pointing a laser directly at their eye to check if they can see it. Do I need to add a hint, that this is a BAD idea?

Comment: @JensSchauder Actually, we make it out to be a worse idea than it really is.  Class IIIa lasers are designed to be *unlikely* to cause damage to the retina.  Now I have my rule about high voltage (don't trust your heart to something someone said on SE), and I suppose it applies to lasers as well (don't trust your eye to something someone said on SE), but it's supposed to take many seconds for a IIIa to cause retinal damage, and generally speaking our blink reflex will ensure this does not happen unless you take efforts to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: The US FDA has issued two notices of *anecdotal* damage due to a particular green laser, but general studies have not found a connection between accidental IIIa exposure and retinal damage.  The only studies to show damage were those which involved prolonged viewing of the beam (10+ seconds)

Answer (score 42):

The reflected light is *moving toward/into your eye*, while the light just passing by you isn't. You can see light that's not "reflected", like the light emitted by a light bulb, there's nothing special about reflected light. All that's needed to see light is the light actually hitting your retina.

Answer (score 18):

The premise of your question is wrong - You can see light direct from a source!

This is what happens when you see the sun or a light bulb or a fire.

Most objects do not make their own light, they are illuminated by the sun or another source and we see them as a result of the sunlight reflected of them. If you go into a cave, you cannot see. Everything looks black because there is no sunlight.

Only the photons entering your eye enable you to see. Photons travel in straight lines, so you cannot see around corners. Your eye is tiny compared to the room you are in, so most of the photons bouncing off the objects around you go in other directions. Some of them may enter your friend's eye if they are with you.

So - what happens to the photons reflected off the objects around you that don't enter your eye? Well, if you are indoors, most of them will be absorbed by other objects and their energy will be dissipated as heat. If you are outside, quite a lot of them will be angled up towards the sky and out into space. Eventually, they may hit a planet or a nebula and be absorbed. It doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the light which enters in your eye and is absorbed by your retina. So you cannot see the light passing by because it is not going towards your eye. If it meets an object, however, light will be reflected or scattered and part of it will go towards your eye. You will then see the light coming from the object.

I would add that if you put your eye before the object, into the light illuminating it, you will see the incoming light just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing an object means that the photons coming from the object (either by reflecting photons from the object or by emitting photons from the object itself) reach your retina which sends signals to your visual cortex, where an image of the object is created.You don't see the photons but the object.

So to see an object like a photon passing you, the photon has to emit itself photons in all directions (or reflect photons shined on it, which is ruled out by QM, because it alters the state of the photon you want to "see", and because the frequencies of photons and the photons you shine on the photons must have frequencies which lie outside the part of the photon frequency spectrum in which the photons are "visible"), a part of which is reaching your retina after which an image of the photon is created in your visual cortex.

Now we all know that photons don't emit photons, so no photons coming from the photon will reach your retina, which is why we can't form an image of a photon in our visual cortex. It just passes by without sending photons to your retina.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a fundamental misapprehension of the way light interacts with an object. Most objects do not reflect light. They absorb light and re-emit it. When you see regular objects like a house or tree, you are not seeing reflected light. You are seeing light which is emitted by the object. The reason why objects have color is because the objects only emit light in certain frequencies. For example, the leaf of a tree absorbs all the red and blue light and re-emits light in the green part of the spectrum. At the atomic level what happens is that the light hits atoms of the object and the electrons of the atoms are momentarily excited. The electrons then return to their normal state and emit new photons in the process. The photons that are emitted are DIFFERENT photons than the ones that came in originally.

Reflected light usually is whitish yellow because that is the color of the sun. Reflected light is what we call "glare". When you see the glare of the sun off the water of a lake that is reflected light. Reflected light bounces off of materials that for whatever reason cannot absorb the light. Reflected light is always whatever color it was originally.

We do not see things from light that is reflected. We see things from the light that they EMIT.

If you want a more technical description description of the interaction of light with matter [read this paper from the Yale astronomy department](http://www.astro.yale.edu/vdbosch/astro320_summary23.pdf) or better yet the lectures of Feynman on the interaction of light with matter.

In short, even though you might read that in "diffuse reflection" the light "bounces" off of the materials atoms, this is not true. It is actually absorped and re-emitted at the same wavelength. This can happen by two mechanisms: Thomson Scattering or Resonant Scattering. Either way, all the photons are absorbed and partially re-admitted (unless the object is black and they are all absorbed.

Comment: Not to nitpick your terminology, but arguably, "absorb light and re-emit it" is the very definition of reflecting light...

Comment: @fluffy Did you even read my answer? When light is reflected, the light bounces off the object. There is only one photon. When light is absorbed and re-emitted, the photons hitting the object are consumed and NEW photons are emitted. It is a completely different type of event.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that most of the light we see from objects is the result of [fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) rather than [diffuse reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection). I don't think that's true; after all, if I shine some blue light on a leaf, it will appear blue, not green. Do you have a source for any of this?

Comment: @TannerSwett This is basic physics. Maybe take a class in physics?

Comment: A reflected photon is always a "new" photon, at the very least because it has a different wavevector. Sure, it is generated in a fixed phase with respect to the incident photon, but it's still a different one. It's counterproductive to limit oneself always to the corpuscular interpretation of em-radiation.

Comment: @TannerSwett I have updated my answer with a paper you can read. Even though many online descriptions of "diffuse reflection" say that the light "bounces" off of atoms, this is not true. As LL1AMnYP says these are not "bounced", they are photons that have been re-emitted at the same frequency/wavelength as the incident radiation.

Comment: Reflected light [is also absorbed and immediately re-emitted by electrons](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83118), in the same sense and by the exact same mechanism as the Thomson scattering described in the astrophysics paper you linked to. It's just that when you have a flat solid surface instead of a cloud of isolated particles, the re-emitted waves interfere with each other, producing a coherent reflection instead of random scattering. Whether you call this "bouncing off the atom" or "absorption and re-emission with the same wavelength and fixed phase difference" is just semantics.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Great, now that we have established that my answer is reasonable, can we upvote it please?

Comment: The usage of "new photon" is scientifically meaningless, since (a) all elementary particles are identical and indistinguishable, and (b) photon numbers do not even conserve, which makes the situation worse. There is NO WAY to test if a photon is the "original" photon, and there is no notion of original-ness and new-ness. Hence the downvote.

Comment: Regardless of semantics, the mechanisms of how reflection work are kind of irrelevant to the question as asked, and this answer does nothing to actually answer the question.

Comment: @fluffy I reckon, the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs should be removed (since the 1st paragraph has just established that "reflected" light is simply "absorbed and then re-emitted" light), then this answer  offers an alternative perspective on OP's problem, i.e. all photons are emitted, there's nothing distinguishing them from "reflected" photons.

Comment: I believe this answer is right. Diving in a little bit deeper. When we are seeing things around us it's basically our brain generating that image. Our eyes has photoreceptors which responds to light. The 3 types of cone cells are, red sensing, blue sensing and green sensing cone cells. The truth is we can only see 3 primary colors and the rest of the colors are generated by the mix of these 3 colors. We only see a small fraction of electromagnetic spectrum this doesn't mean that only this part is colorful and rest is not. There are some proves to justify it. Like some birds have 4 cone cells.

Comment: That help those bird to see even the ultraviolet rays. Mantis shrimp have 12 types of cone cells. And there are some humans too, though very rare, who also have 4 types of cone cells, there eyes can generate more colors than we do. So with respect to them we are color blind. And those people we call colorblind are the one who have 2 types of cone cells, that means maybe they can see  blue or green but not red. And in some extreme cases people lack all the three cone cells which makes them see in grayscale.

Comment: This proves that color is not the property of matter. Color is something that our brain generates. And same goes with sound. Sound is also a wave. we have audible range , infrasonic and ultrasonic sound. And our brain can only generate a small fraction of sound frequency we call audible range. Some animals can hear beyond that. Like elephants communicate in infrasonic, and dogs can hear dog whistles but we can't. Those people who are downvoting are simply ignorant.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi Color is a property of light according to its frequency. Light emitted by a object will vary somewhat in color depending on the color of light that impinges on it. Color does not depend on the brain or other perception. Color can be absolutely detected by instruments such as colorimeters with no need of a brain to perceive it.

Comment: @AmbroseSwasey I don't agree with that. First of all, we should begin with what color is? Colour is the "visual perceptual" property corresponding in humans to the categories called blue, green, red, etc. "~wiki.  lights are not colorful. Think clearly what is light? An oscillating electromagnetic field. How can electromagnetic field can have color. Color is what we perceive, and all that happens inside our visual cortex. Color is not the property of matter or light rather color and vision is a physiological phenomena.

Comment: "Checker shadow illusion" will help you clearly understand this, search for it. In that image, both the tiles are of exactly same color but appears to be different due to optical illusion. If color is really a property of light then explain how some people are color-blind, because light is light and it's same for everyone, but the cone cells are different in different creatures. That is what I explained above.

Comment: Then why do we say red light, blue light and green light? It's because we have assigned the word red with the electromagnetic wave of frequency ranging from 620-750 nm, and similarly for other. And when the electromagnetic wave of suppose 7--nm strikes our retina a red colored image is generated inside our brain. And colorimeter/spectrophotometers or any other color sensing devices detects the wavelengths of light and not actually perceive the color. Suppose, if a device says 450 nm of wavelength we will mean it detected blue color.

Comment: Also if you look at the world from a different animal's perspective the world will look different to you. The visual range, colors, audible range are only applicable for us humans only.

Comment: And why do we see certain colors only is connected with human evolution. Our body has evolved to see light beyond infrared rays it's because any warm-blooded animals emit high amount of infrared rays. So if we were able to detect infrared then we would be blinded by the emission of our infrared rays, and that's why creatures like snakes which are cold-blooded are evolved to see infrared rays so that they can hunt their prays even in night. Because even there is no light the warm blooded animals are emitting infrared rays due to their warmer body.

Answer (score -5):

Well done. You grasp a concept which many can't. The simplest explanation is that we don't see light, we feel light. By light I mean photons, not brightness. We see brightness because it is a visual sensation created by our brain. When our retina detects a photon it sends a message to the brain and the brain interprets this message as an image. Everything you see is created by the brain. A 3 dimensional visual representation of our surroundings.

Seeing something means detecting the shape, size, location and what wavelength of light it reflects (colour), without touching it. We only detect light that strikes our retina. Therefore we feel light, we don't see light. Feeling light is part of the process we call seeing.

Comment: As I said, very few people grasp this concept but if you are interested in the truth, read page 108 and 109.https://books.google.co.za/books?dq=do+we+see+or+feel+photons%3F&hl=en&id=rPNHAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA109&ots=z-SPeSNkqN&pg=PA109&sa=X&sig=DNk__1lCk-GcaYSeMXSSoBeUsFs&source=bl&ved=0ahUKEwiytpf1m43TAhWBCMAKHZ9vAUEQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=do%20we%20see%20or%20feel%20photons%3F&f=false