# Experiment carried out to measure the Huygenian wave behind an opening all over 180°

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, huygens-principle

I‘m curios about the verification of the Huygens-Fresnel principle for light. For water it is clear visible in experiments, that the wave behind an opening disperses out all over 180°.

For light the same is claimed, like we see it in the sketch, I took from [ad2004](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/589120/46708)s answer to another question.
[image]

With naked eye, I‘m not able to see any light from very close to + an -90° from the obstacle with the slit. I’m curious about experimental results with sensitive enough instruments.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is the diffraction pattern from a single slit as described in [How can a single slit diffraction produce an interference pattern?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61455/how-can-a-single-slit-diffraction-produce-an-interference-pattern) The intensity as a function of angle [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction):

$$ I(\theta) = I_0 ~ \mathrm{sinc}^2 \left(\frac{d\pi\sin\theta}{\lambda}\right) $$

where $d$ is the slit width and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light.

To observe this yourself is quite hard as the intensity falls rapidly with angle unless the slit width is comparable to the wavelength. When I did the experiment as part of my physics practicals we used a laser in a darkroom. A Google image search will find you many examples of the diffraction pattern.

Comment: John, especially at the closest positions to the wall nearly +/-90° from the laser direction), did you get any light? For water waves one see the wave dispersing with naked eyes. Today we are able to detect even single photons, has an experimentator seen light in these extremal positions?